# Prestashop 1.6.0.9 override and performances : file class_index.php has disappeared

Tags: performance, overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Since a couple of days, after the update to PS 1.6.0.9, the file /cache/class_index.php is not created anymore. Actually, in the /cache folder, there is only one folder : ./smarty

Every overridden files work, but I guess this is bad for performances. How prestashop know which file to use ? (Core or Override) Does it have to look in the /override folder each time?

Is there something to enable to have it back?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
[The solution came from Pete78 from the Prestashop Forum](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/349796-solved-1609-class-indexphp-has-disappeared/?p=1762987)

> In my case it was a bug in PrestaShopAutoLoad.class
>   I replaced the one in 1.6.0.9 with the latest from github and class_index.php was recreated again.. [PrestaShopAutoLoad.class on GitHub](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/8288a6fffa0eb7a42b280298f798ff9292dd7be3/classes/PrestaShopAutoload.php)

Answer (score 2):

I'm don't know English that well but for a start look at the `classes/PrestaShopAutoload.php`.

Have a look at line 35:

```
const INDEX_FILE = 'cache/class_index.php';
```

Try to replace this with:

```
const INDEX_FILE = '/cache/class_index.php';
```